# Django queryset filter max values for list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm wondering if there is any way to pass a list to a django queryset and limit to the max/min/latest/oldest value for each item in the list.

Basically something like this:

```
serial_list = [2231, 2232, 2233]
data_queryset = Data.objects.filter(serial__in=serial_list).latest()
```

I'm fully aware that the above code doesn't work. I'm just trying to illustrate a queryset that would return the `.latest()` value for each object where the `serial` is in `serial_list`.

Comment: That code does work, have you tried with a date field e.g.: `Data.objects.filter(serial__in=serial_list).latest('date_field_name')` ?

Comment: @heemayl that only returns a single object; The latest object in the queryset. I'm trying to get a latest object for each item in the list. So in this case, the queryset should have three objects. The latest for each serial in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the `serial_list`, and for each one get the `latest()` element from the queryset after querying the model. Here, using a dict comprehension to set each iterated item from `serial_list` as key and relevant `latest()` item on queryset as value:

```
serial_list = [2231, 2232, 2233]
{serial_: Data.objects.filter(serial=serial_).latest('date_field') \
           for serial_ in serial_list}
```

Comment: This works! I hadn't thought to use a dictionary like that